# Sql query to find records with column value is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find records with Column value is blank. as you can see in the table I have records with following values when I fire a Distinct query on the Column MOVE_STU.

[image: Out of Distinct Query]

now I can find all the record with column value related to (1,2,3,4 and 6) but I'm not able to find the records with Column Value related to (5). as there are Thousands of record in the table i'm not able to figure out how should I write query in order to get these records. Kindly help. Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use trim and comparison with empty string to get records that contain only whitespaces:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(MOVE_STU)) = ''
```

Comment: Zero Records Found. Even I Tried Select * from Table where MOVE_STU not in('1','2','3','C',null) Still no records found

Comment: @PratikDhole When you use `NOT IN` your subquery/value list should not contain `NULL` otherwise it always returns empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(YourField)) = ''
```

This will give you all matches that are empty, or have only whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE MOVE_STU = ''

SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ISNULL(MOVE_STU,'') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

If your datatype is int then you have to change in varchar

```
ALTER TABLE [tbl_name] ALTER COLUMN [MOVE_STU] [VARCHAR(50)];
```

then run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl_name] WHERE MOVE_STU IS NULL;
```